# Recursion. What's the difference between return func() and if (func()) return true?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm writing a Sudoku solver and I've got working solve function.

```
bool Sudoku::solve(int row, int col){
    while (board[row][col] != 0){
        col++;

        if (col > 8){
            col = 0;
            row ++;
        }

        if (row > 8){
            return true;
        }
    }

    for (int number = 1; number <= 9; number++){
        board[row][col] = number;

        if (check_row(row,number) && check_col(col,number) && check_box(row,col,number)){
            int next_row = row;
            int next_col = col;

            next_col++;

            if (next_col > 8){
                next_col = 0;
                next_row++;
            }

            if (next_row > 8)
                return true;


            // return solve(next_row, next_col);
            if (solve(next_row, next_col))
                return true;
        }
    }

    board[row][col] = 0;
    return false;
}
```

And I can't really understand what's the difference between

```
if (solve(next_row, next_col))
    return true;
```

and

```
return solve(next_row, next_col);
```

however with the second line my function doesn';t work

Comment: The second one always returns something. The first one continues on if the condition is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `solve(next_row, next_col)` is false first one will continue function execution. And the second will just return false.

Answer (score 0):

With `if (solve(next_row, next_col)) return true;` the execution continues to the next line if false. The return is only evaluated if true. This means that `board[row][col] = 0;` will be executed if the condition is false in the first one but not in the second.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, there are two differences between

> if (solve()) return true;

and

> return solve();

The first difference is that the function will continue rather than exit if the return value from solve evaluates as true.  The second difference is that in the second line solve() would not have to return `true` or `false` but could return a non-zero value rather than `true` (if the solve() function did not return a `bool` value).

Answer (score 0):

First case:

```
if (solve(next_row, next_col))
    return true;
```

In this case it returns true when the solve function returns true and never returns false.

Second Case:

```
return solve(next_row, next_col);
```

It returns true if `solve` returns true and returns false otherwise.